# How to remove specials characters, but replace spaces?

Tags: postgresql, replace, string-manipulation

I have a string with spaces & special characters: `ABC%$! DEF*& GHI`

I want to remove all the specials characters, but replace the spaces with an underscore:  `ABC_DEF_GHI`

I have:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(c.category_name, '[^\w]+','','g')
```

But that removes all the characters, including spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Do the space-to-underscore [replace()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.26.1.1.1) first, and your existing expression will do the rest.

```
testdb=# select regexp_replace(replace('ABC%$! DEF*& GHI', ' ', '_'), '[^\w]+','','g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 ABC_DEF_GHI
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** there is a short, static list of possible special characters, [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is typically much faster:

```
test=> SELECT translate('ABC%$! DEF*& GHI', ' %$!*&', '_');
  translate  
-------------
 ABC_DEF_GHI
```

Every listed character with no replacement is removed.
Else, consider Adam's answer.

But I suppose you wouldn't want leading or trailing `_` in the result? May surface *after* removing noise characters. So feed the result to [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL):

```
test=> SELECT translate('ABC%$! DEF*& GHI %', ' %$!*&', '_')
test-> , trim(translate('ABC%$! DEF*& GHI %', ' %$!*&', '_'), '_');
  translate   |    btrim    
--------------+-------------
 ABC_DEF_GHI_ | ABC_DEF_GHI
```